# Recursive asynchronouse function with mongoose saving inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have a problem with quite a complex function I am trying to build It is asynchronous and recursive and based on the tree of nodes it is to create their instances in the Mongoose database.

The sample data Im sending can look like this:

```
parent1{[name:"Name1", children:[{name:Name2, children[{name:Name4, children:[]}]}, {name: Name3, children:[]}]
```

So ideally it is to get the children of Name1 (Name2 and Name3) then iteratre through them, getting first to Name2 and recursively to its children, hence froming Name4 as first, then Name2, then go to Name3 and as it has no children, save it. I am trying to make the code stop when creating the item (ergo: Name3 is created in the db only after Name4 is created, and Name3 is created in the end). I am using the following code, based on what I have found on stackoverflow so far:

```
async function recurrentlyCreateChildren(childrenArray){
  if(childrenArray.length>0){
    await childrenArray.reduce(async(child) => {
      if(child.children.length>0){
        recurrentlyCreateChildren(child.children);
        tempDic=  new Node({
          name: child.name,
          children: [],
        });

        await tempDic.save(function(err, dicSystem) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Success");
          }else{
            console.log("SAVED");
          }
        });
      }else{
        tempDic=  new Node({
          name: child.name,
          children: [],
        });
        await tempDic.save(function(err, dicSystem) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("SHOW US ERROR", err);
          }else{
            console.log("SAVED");
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return;
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

However, the nodes are formed quite randomly (also, it doesnt get to Name3, just creates Name2). How can I change it so it performs as intended?

Comment: you cannot use `await` with callbacks...it doesnt work that way. the function you `await` needs to return a promise.

Comment: Your usage of `reduce` makes no sense, where is your accumulator? Use a plain `for…of` loop instead.

Comment: @Bergi - but also asynchronously, correct?

Comment: Yes, keep the `await tempDic.save();`. But remove the callback, iirc mongoose methods don't return a promise if you pass one.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately the problem remains - they are just created asynchrously, but not in the order inteded (required for other usage). It also doesn't create Name3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to change:

- don't use `reduce` (where you're not using the accumulator correctly) but a plain loop
- don't pass a callback to the `save` method to make it return a promise
- actually `await` the recursive call as well
- remove the unnecessary conditions

```js
async function createChildren(childrenArray) {
  for (const child of childrenArray) {
    await recurrentlyCreateChildren(child.children);

    const tempDic = new Node({
      name: child.name,
      children: [],
    });
    await tempDic.save();
    console.log("Saved", child.name);
  }
  console.log("Saved all "+childrenArray.length+" children");
}
```